# Boolean comparison of array with vector to yield a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following vectors:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0.4, 0.6])
y = np.array([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])
```

What operation would get me a matrix that looks like this?

```
False False True False False False
False False False True False False
```

In other words, all Falses except where the values from x appear in y by row.  Note that I can't have for loops because this is a toy example for my use case case that deals with large matrices.

Comment: ```x[:, None] == y```

Comment: Or, `np.isclose(x[:,None], y)`. Since comparing floats with `==` is very rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the comments from Nin17 and chrslg and made them into an answer. Either one works, `x[:, None] == y`, or `np.isclose(x[:,None], y)`. After testing with the amount of time each takes, I found the average time per operation for lists of varying sizes from 1-2000:

```py
x[:, None] == y #0.0009190634489059448 sec
np.isclose(x[:,None], y) #0.0032343467473983766 sec
```

Though the times indicate that the `x[:, None] == y` or even `x.round(z)[:, None] == y.round(z) #0.0010015535354614257 sec` may seem faster, `np.close` has the benefit of keeping the intent of comparing the values without the chance of numerical errors with using `==`. Many examples can be seen in the comments.

Comment: The rounding amount would need to be determined on a case-by-case. In general, the `np.isclose` method is better since it preserves more of the intent.

Comment: `x=np.array([17836,  1312, 37510, 31775])`. `r1=x[0]/x[1]+x[2]/x[3]`. `r2=(x[0]*x[3]+x[2]*x[1])/(x[1]*x[3])`. `r1==r2` → False. `r1.round(2)==r2.round(2)` → False. `np.isclose(r1, r2)` → True.

Comment: The problem with `round` is the same (but less rough) as with just comparing `int` values: not only if may force a too large tolerance (but you can solve that by choosing the number of decimal places), but as large the tolerance is, you may end up with 2 extremely close values, one falling just before the boundaries between two rounded values, the other, just after. In my previous example, `r1` ends up being `14.774999999999999` while `r2` is `14.775`. Both should be the same obviously (that is just 2 ways of computing `a/b+c/d`), but numerical error, a very small one (~10⁻¹⁵), is sufficient

Comment: so that `r1.round(2)` is `14.77` rand `r2.round(2)` is `14.78`

Comment: (Obviously, as you can imagine, I had to search for this example. And search hard. It needs bad luck, that I've forced here. I had to do choose 40 millions values (`a=np.random.randint(1,40000,10000000)`), and then check if `((a[:,0]/a[:,1]+a[:,2]/a[:,3]).round(2)==((a[:,0]*a[:,3]+a[:,2]*a[:,1])/(a[:,1]*a[:,3])).round(2)).all()`. And if False, to look at the row at line `.argmin()` of that. So it is a once every millions cases error. Yet, it is an error, that is not justified by numerical error. Such a simple computation should be almost exact, and with the intended 0.01 tolerance margin

Comment: it should not be possible to find a counter example to that `a/b+c/d == (a*d+b*c)/(b*d)` formula, with a,b,c,d being just integers.

Comment: You can't fail `np.isclose` that way. Even with billions of examples, and even with a smaller tolerance, that can't happen. Because there is no threshold effect, as with `np.round`.

Comment: For `==`, of course, no need to random search counter example. The infamous `0.1+0.2==0.3`→False is well known.

Comment: In the mean time, I found a clearer counter example: `np.round(0.13+0.015,2) == np.round(0.145,2)` → False. In fact, you can produce many of them, with just the pattern `a.bc + d.ef5`. Just the same principle as with 0.1+0.2: there is a numerical error, unless the numbers are of the form k/2ⁿ, with k integer. And half of the numerical errors, since exact result is of the form `?.??5`, will change the outcome of `round(?,2)`. So for example, starting with 0, any `0.xy` except 0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75 (that are k/4), plus any `0.zt5`, except 0.125, 0.375, 0.625, 0.875, are candidate for a problem

Comment: Sorry if I seem to heavily insist on it. I am sure my first comment was sufficient to prove my point, and my intention is not to bury you in many arguments. But I had some fun trying to explore how to build counter-examples, so I shared it :D.